# Python stop and start directory observer

Tags: python, python-3.x, watchdog, fileobserver

I have a GUI and a button that toggles an observer.

```
def start(self):
    self.observer.schedule(event_handler=update, path=self.path, recursive=False)
    self.observer.start()

def stop(self):
    self.observer.unschedule_all()
    self.observer.stop()
    self.observer.join()
```

But when I run the start method again I get a RunTimeError: `threads can only be started once`

Comment: You're probably getting that error because you're trying to start a thread more than once and threads can't be started more than once.

Comment: I put the start call in the constructor and it works. Thought the stop function is the opposite of the start function